# What is a good beginner reading-level Bible book for adults?

Tags: resource-request, books, bible-reading

I have a friend who is foreign born and her English is good but she needs to improve her reading and writing skills. It is jeopardizing her job situation because she can't read/write emails very well. I want to suggest some books for her to read that will help her improve her skills. However, she is very religious, and would only be interested in reading Bible-related books.

She reads from the King James Bible every day for ~30 mins, but it is in old english, and I am not sure that she understands what she is reading. But she reads it religiously. Is there a more modern Bible-related book that I can suggest for her? Something that would help her understand modern grammar and sentence structure would be best, especially for improving her written communication in daily life.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Is there any reason she cannot simply read a modern translation? The KJV is very good but it's still only a translation.

Comment: Take your friend to a Christian Book Store so she can see for herself which books or translations are best suited for her situation. As your question stands now it seems very broad for this site.

Comment: Your friend might enjoy reading the Open Bible Stories from unfoldingword.org or their cell phone app. These are intended to be the first Bible material translated into a new language, so the stories should be very familiar to her and easy to read. Also Youversion.com and theword.net have several digital bibles available at no charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love the New International Version for easier reading.. Or even the New KIng James is better than the old using ye olde englishe :) Or the "Good News Bible" may be even better!

I also love, even as an adult, some of the Bibles for Children. And as far as sentence structure, would, I think, be good for beginning to learn good sentence structure. And some I'm sure are put out by the King James publishers(?)